# Como importar os pacotes Lua para o Love?

Tags: lua, löve

Estava observando os arquivos de exemplo do lua (mais especificadamente o iup), e o exemplo dial.wlua chamou bastante a minha atenção... Achei que seria interessante um jogo usando essa base, para viagens no tempo, por exemplo, e tentei importar o pacote iuplua ao main.lua (colocando no início do código: `require("iuplua")` e `require("iupluacontrols")` ). Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resumindo: **Como posso importar esse e outros pacotes do lua para o löve2D?**

Answer (score 1):

Quando você dá um `require("iup")`, o interpretador vai procurar pelo arquivo do iup em uma série de diretórios, [dependendo da configuração do seu sistema de módulos](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/pt/manual.html#pdf-require). No seu caso, os lugares em que o LOVE procurou pelo iup aparecem na mensagem de erro. A maneira mais simples de resolver o problema seria movendo o arquivo do iup para um desses diretórios.

Comment: Curiosamente, não tem nenhum arquivo "iuplua.dll", então resolvi copiar todos os arquivos com o prefixo iup, e mesmo assim mesmo erro... Percebi que existia o "iuplua51.dll", e tentei requerer ele, e o resultado é que ele simplesmente inicia e se fecha na hora, como se abrisse, desse um erro e se fechasse, mas não me imprimi qualquer erro! Tentei mudar o nome do "iuplua51.dll" para "iuplua.dll", e a mesma falha estranha acontece!